# BMI if statements using return

Tags: android-studio-2.3

This is my code on if statement but I am warned that it cant return because I use void type,please help

```
if (BMI < 18.5)
return " You are underweight";
if ((BMI >= 18.5) && (BMI < 24.5))
 return " You are normal weight.";
else if (BMI > 25)
    return " You are overweight.";
else (BMI>30)
                        return "You are Obese!";
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a part of a method, you should define it with return type String and not with void.

```
public String myMethod(...some args...){
    your code...
```

and not

```
public void myMethod(...some args...){
```